# Route planning in public transport application

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithm, path-finding, transport, jgrapht

I'm making a journey planner (or a general timetable application) for all the public transport in my country (bus/train/air).

The state of the project is at midpoint, now I'm having a bit of a hard time getting the more difficult part of the application done.

To describe the current status:

- The data is stored in a MySQL database, modeled as GTFS (General (Google) Transit Feed Specification)
- I'm getting the direct routes by simply querying the database (join of a two temp tables, I find it as efficient enough)
- Currently it's done in PHP, but I can re-work it in Java, if needed

So, when there are direct connections between two points, all is fine. The hard part is getting a complete journey when there are no direct lines.

Say the user wants to travel from `city A` to `city D`, but because there are no direct lines between those cities, he needs to pass through `city B` and `city C`.

How can I get the optimized routes and *transfers* for this situation?

My ideas so far a gravitating towards using a graph, but in that case I need a **Time-Dependant Directed Weighted Multigraph**, and I really have no idea at the moment how to implement the **Time-Dependant** part.

Getting just the route can be done by using `Dijkstra`, `A*` or `Floyd–Warshall` algorithms , but because there are departures at different times, I'm not sure how will this be implemented, to get the optimal solution. I need to take into consideration the duration of a segment (A to B, B to C), waiting time for the transfer, maybe the distance too.

Just to clarify, I don't need a single result. I want to get a daily list of all departures from `city A` that can get the user to `city D`, with transfers if needed.

Basically, what I'm trying to get is something like this (taken from Bulgarian Railways, or for that matter, whichever railway site), a list of all departures for a chosen day going from `Sofia` to `Kystendil` making transfer in `Radomir` if needed:

[image: Sample Result]

About the graph solving part, I can make an application in Java using [jGraphT](http://jgrapht.org/), cache the results (they change once in every few months maybe), and use them in PHP (or call the application through PHP).

If I'm not clear enough, please ask.

I know that this is done so many times (almost any train website has the solutions), but I don't know by which terms to even search.

**So, my question is: can someone give me guidance how this type of problem is solved?**

**Or at least by which terms should I search for ideas and how should it be done.**

Maybe some suggestions for other sites in the StackExchange network.

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look into OpenTripPlanner

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938954/is-there-is-a-route-from-city-a-to-city-b-in-no-more-than-x-days).

Comment: I don't want to revive this one, since there are multiple dublicates of it anyway. In PHP, you are most likely doomed. Here is [my extensive answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29143650/how-to-store-public-transportation-data/29144899#29144899).