# Application searching railway connections

Tags: sql, algorithm, graph

I am managing a project which can be described as below.

Application should display train connections from city A to city B, with optimization on grounds of total travel time, total kilometres, waiting time on station etc. It has more requirements, but they are not so hard so I can handle it alone.

I would like to receive proposition for implementation. I was thinking about indirected graph where cities are vertices and railways are edges. Every single railway would have start city, end city, length and maybe some other parameters.

The main problem is following: in a database there will be trains with specified start station, end station and intermediate station, with given arrival and departure time. **What algorithm would you propose that would be able to find the best connection from city A to city B?**

I am thinking about the following: there would be matrix of dimension `A[n][n]`, where `n` is the number of cities. Let `a` and `b` be ID of cities A and B. If there exists direct train from A to B,  `A[a][b]=1`, else `A[a][b]=0`. If there does not exist such cennection, system tries to find connection through city which is connected with A and with B. Is it efficient solution?

Comment: You have to think in numerical ization of this data. where the lower sum value of connections should be the best.

Comment: Okay, so you suggest to make low number of connection the most desired state? I approve this:) nevertheless optimization is rather a problem for the future considering that I have not written any algorithm yet. Thanks for help :)

Comment: Not only the low number of connection. It may be something like Google pagerank, in which every connection has a rank and the total rank sum will going to be the favorite one.

Comment: Very closely related to [Is there is a route from city a to city b in no more than x days?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938954/is-there-is-a-route-from-city-a-to-city-b-in-no-more-than-x-days/15943928#15943928) My answer there would allow you to take waiting time into account as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create edges for each segment of track, so you can model junctions and sidings and the like. Nodes combine each of these edges together, they don't need to be only stations.

Then get yourself boost::graph and use one of its algorithms to do all the hard work for you :) Suggested ones are A* or Dijkstra.